# Why does Visual Studio Code open my PowerShell files in a separate shell using 5.1 instead of Core?

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-core

I have `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PowerShell\\6\\pwsh.exe"` set in my settings.json file, and when I open VS code without any files open the terminal is set to pwsh, but when I open a PowerShell script, there is suddenly a second terminal (PowerShell Integrated Console) and running the debugger results in PowerShell 5.1 being used instead of 6 (Core).

What do I need to do to get PowerShell version 6 used whenever I open a .ps1 document? Running it from the command line works, but is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell Integrated Console is what the PowerShell extension uses to process .ps1 files and is controlled by a different setting (powershell.powerShellExePath).

You can change this setting easily by opening a .ps1 file, then clicking on the "5.1", "6.0", etc. icon in the bottom right of the status bar. This will open the PowerShell Session Menu where you can select which version of PowerShell you want the extension to use (out of the versions you have installed).

Your choice will then be persisted in your user settings under powershell.powerShellExePath.